# Can a tableViewCell be both movable and have a swipe action with editing style of .none

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a standard UITableView with the following criteria:

1) The cells need to be movable all the time with the hamburger icon on the right

2) The cells need a swipe action.

3) The cells can't have the default iOS delete icon (little red circle with a (-) in it) on the left side

I've tried with a sample project with the following code implemented for the table

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView : UITableView!

var myArray = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTableView.delegate = self
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self

    myTableView?.register(myTableCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: myTableCell.identifier)

    myTableView.isEditing = true

}
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
     return myArray.count 
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
     return true
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle { 
     return .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myTableCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? myTableCell else {
        return myTableCell()
    }
    cell.label.text = myArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.showsReorderControl = true
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let rowToMove = myArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
    myArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    myArray.insert(rowToMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction : UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (action,indexPath) -> Void in
        self.myArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    })
    return [deleteAction]
}
}
```

I can get either the swipe to delete or the move code to work if I comment out the functionality of the other, but I'm curious if it's possible to get both.

Thanks

Comment: No..!! its not possible I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this issue today. Here is what I learned: UITableView has an .editing property - This is the key that toggles on/off swipe actions and moving cells.

When tableView.editing is true -> Then tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and swipe actions are disabled, while UITableViewCell's can be 'edited' (moved for example).

When tableView.editing is false -> Then tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and swipe actions work, and UITableViewCell's cannot be 'edited' (they cannot be dragged/moved for example).

It appears that without digging under the hood your conditions are mutually exclusive, unfortunately. The best easy solution I envision is toggling the UITableView's .editing state through a button or gesture (perhaps a long press on the UITableView).

(Maybe this should be a comment - I don't have enough points/karma to write comments - sorry if I am breaking protocol, I'm just trying to be useful!)

Comment: This is the conclusion that I came to as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for anyone who may still have this question:

UITableView has a private `allowsReorderingWhenNotEditing` property that can be seen in the [decompiled header](https://developer.limneos.net/?ios=14.4&framework=UIKitCore.framework&header=UITableView.h).

You can use `tableView.setValue(true, forKey: "allowsReorderingWhenNotEditing")` to achieve the behaviour you want. Note, you'll need to set `tableView.isEditting` to `false` for the swipe actions to work, but you'll now have reordering enabled in spite of this.

Fair warning, this is a private API, there's no guarantee that this will make it past App Review.

Comment: Warning 2: The `setValue` line could crash in any future iOS update if the private API changes.

Comment: FYI - you don't need to use this private API at all. Reordering can be done via table view's support for drag and drop.